# Is there a way to plug in standalone function that would return `bool` and would be called in jQuery Validate pipeline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am working with MVC, jQuery, and jQuery Validate plugin.

I am having problem with using jQuery Validate on set of fields that when validated can be visible or not.

If customer selects `radiobutton` that he has additional address, postcode field is being shown. This field has required validator on it that works just fine. However when user enters postcode he has to click `Find Address` button and then ajax call is being made and addresses for that postcode are shown. Then user has to click on address and it gets selected.

Problems that I am having:

1. When user enters postcode and submits the form without clicking `Find Address` validation passes because required validation is passed.
2. When user enters postcode and clicks `Find Address` but does not choose address from the list and submits the form validation is passed.

There are non visible fields to which address is being populated so I could un-ignore those specific fields to be validated by removing then from ignore list

```
ignore: ":hidden, :hidden:not(#HiddenAddressFields)"
```

but this is conditional so in validation method that I would register with

```
$.validator.addMethod("mainAddressValidator", function() {
   ...
});
```

I would have to do logic that would be checking should these fields be validated, plus this might cause side effects and list of hidden fields is long. Another reason I don't like this is since we are using bundling this would 'leak' to all other pages.

**Is there a way to plug in standalone function that would return `bool` and would be called in JQuery form validation pipeline that would not depend on elements being visible (or anything for that matter)?**

**HTML** (not that I think this helps but someone will ask for it anyway)

```
<div class="form-group" id="IsMainResidence">
    <div class="col-md-12 field-wrapper">
<label class="" for="IsMainResidence">Do you wish for correspondence to be sent to this address?</label>        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9 radio-align fake-radio">
                    <div class="radio inline">                                  
                        <input checked="checked" class="tooltip" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select whether the property is your main residence" id="IsMainResidencetrue" name="IsMainResidence" type="radio" value="True"><label for="IsMainResidencetrue"><strong>Yes</strong></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio inline">
                        <input class="tooltip" id="IsMainResidencefalse" name="IsMainResidence" type="radio" value="False"><label for="IsMainResidencefalse"><strong>No</strong></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-6  col-xs-3">
                        <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs tick-validation-valid"></span>
                                        <img alt="help" class="tooltip" id="help-IsMainResidence" src="/legal-services/Client/images/home/help-button.png">             </div>
            </div>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IsMainResidence" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>           <div class="tooltip-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home-address-section" style="display:none;">
<input id="MainResidenceAddressSection_IsIncluded" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.IsIncluded" type="hidden" value="False">
    <!--Home address details start-->
    <div id="MainResidenceDetails">
        <div id="MainResidenceAddressErrorMessage" class="error-group-container" style="display: none;">
            <p class="error-group-text"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="MainResidenceAddressSearch" style="margin-bottom: 20px; ">
            <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="" for="MainResidenceAddressSection_PostcodeForSearch">What is your postcode?</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                    <input class="tooltip form-control" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter a valid postcode" data-val-regex-pattern="^(([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$)" data-val-required="Please enter your postcode" data-val-restrictedpostcode="Sorry, we do not operate in the postcode provided" data-val-restrictedpostcode-postcodelist="AB1,AB2,AB3,AB4,AB5,AB6,AB7,AB8,AB9,AB10,AB11,AB12,AB13,AB14,AB15,AB16,AB17,AB18,AB19,AB20,AB21,AB22,AB23,AB24,AB25,AB26,AB27,AB28,AB29,AB30,AB31,AB32,AB33,AB34,AB35,AB36,AB37,AB38,AB39,AB40,AB41,AB42,AB43,AB44,AB45,AB46,AB47,AB48,AB49,AB50,AB51,AB52,AB53,AB54,AB55,AB56,AB57,AB58,AB59,AB60,AB61,AB62,AB63,AB64,AB65,AB66,AB67,AB68,AB69,AB70,AB71,AB72,AB73,AB74,AB75,AB76,AB77,AB78,AB79,AB80,AB81,AB82,AB83,AB84,AB85,AB86,AB87,AB88,AB89,AB90,AB91,AB92,AB93,AB94,AB95,AB96,AB97,AB98,AB99,BT1,BT2,BT3,BT4,BT5,BT6,BT7,BT8,BT9,BT10,BT11,BT12,BT13,BT14,BT15,BT16,BT17,BT18,BT19,BT20,BT21,BT22,BT23,BT24,BT25,BT26,BT27,BT28,BT29,BT30,BT31,BT32,BT33,BT34,BT35,BT36,BT37,BT38,BT39,BT40,BT41,BT42,BT43,BT44,BT45,BT46,BT47,BT48,BT49,BT50,BT51,BT52,BT53,BT54,BT55,BT56,BT57,BT58,BT59,BT60,BT61,BT62,BT63,BT64,BT65,BT66,BT67,BT68,BT69,BT70,BT71,BT72,BT73,BT74,BT75,BT76,BT77,BT78,BT79,BT80,BT81,BT82,BT83,BT84,BT85,BT86,BT87,BT88,BT89,BT90,BT91,BT92,BT93,BT94,DD1,DD2,DD3,DD4,DD5,DD6,DD7,DD8,DD9,DD10,DD11,DG1,DG2,DG3,DG4,DG5,DG6,DG7,DG8,DG9,DG10,DG11,DG12,DG13,DG14,DG15,DG16,EH1,EH2,EH3,EH4,EH5,EH6,EH7,EH8,EH9,EH10,EH11,EH12,EH13,EH14,EH15,EH16,EH17,EH18,EH19,EH20,EH21,EH22,EH23,EH24,EH25,EH26,EH27,EH28,EH29,EH30,EH31,EH32,EH33,EH34,EH35,EH36,EH37,EH38,EH39,EH40,EH41,EH42,EH43,EH44,EH45,EH46,EH47,EH48,EH49,EH50,EH51,EH52,EH53,EH54,EH55,EH56,EH57,EH58,EH59,EH60,EH61,EH62,EH63,EH64,EH65,EH66,EH67,EH68,EH69,EH70,EH71,EH72,EH73,EH74,EH75,EH76,EH77,EH78,EH79,EH80,EH81,EH82,EH83,EH84,EH85,EH86,EH87,EH88,EH89,EH90,EH91,EH92,EH93,EH94,EH95,EH96,EH97,EH98,EH99,FK1,FK2,FK3,FK4,FK5,FK6,FK7,FK8,FK9,FK10,FK11,FK12,FK13,FK14,FK15,FK16,FK17,FK18,FK19,FK20,FK21,GY1,GY2,GY3,GY4,GY5,GY6,GY7,GY8,GY9,GY10,G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,G10,G11,G12,G13,G14,G15,G16,G17,G18,G19,G20,G21,G22,G23,G24,G25,G26,G27,G28,G29,G30,G31,G32,G33,G34,G35,G36,G37,G38,G39,G40,G41,G42,G43,G44,G45,G46,G47,G48,G49,G50,G51,G52,G53,G54,G55,G56,G57,G58,G59,G60,G61,G62,G63,G64,G65,G66,G67,G68,G69,G70,G71,G72,G73,G74,G75,G76,G77,G78,G79,G80,G81,G82,G83,G84,G85,G86,G87,G88,G89,G90,HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IM1,IM2,IM3,IM4,IM5,IM6,IM7,IM8,IM9,IM86,IM87,IM99,IV1,IV2,IV3,IV4,IV5,IV6,IV7,IV8,IV9,IV10,IV11,IV12,IV13,IV14,IV15,IV16,IV17,IV18,IV19,IV20,IV21,IV22,IV23,IV24,IV25,IV26,IV27,IV28,IV29,IV30,IV31,IV32,IV33,IV34,IV35,IV36,IV37,IV38,IV39,IV40,IV41,IV42,IV43,IV44,IV45,IV46,IV47,IV48,IV49,IV50,IV51,IV52,IV53,IV54,IV55,IV56,IV57,IV58,IV59,IV60,IV61,IV62,IV63,IV64,IV65,IV66,IV67,IV68,IV69,IV70,IV71,IV72,IV73,IV74,IV75,IV76,IV77,IV78,IV79,IV80,IV81,IV82,IV83,IV84,IV85,IV86,IV87,IV88,IV89,IV90,IV91,IV92,IV93,IV94,IV95,IV96,IV97,IV98,IV99,JE1,JE2,JE3,JE4,JE5,KA1,KA2,KA3,KA4,KA5,KA6,KA7,KA8,KA9,KA10,KA11,KA12,KA13,KA14,KA15,KA16,KA17,KA18,KA19,KA20,KA21,KA22,KA23,KA24,KA25,KA26,KA27,KA28,KA29,KA30,KW1,KW2,KW3,KW4,KW5,KW6,KW7,KW8,KW9,KW10,KW11,KW12,KW13,KW14,KW15,KW16,KW17,KY1,KY2,KY3,KY4,KY5,KY6,KY7,KY8,KY9,KY10,KY11,KY12,KY13,KY14,KY15,KY16,KY99,ML1,ML2,ML3,ML4,ML5,ML6,ML7,ML8,ML9,ML10,ML11,ML12,PA1,PA2,PA3,PA4,PA5,PA6,PA7,PA8,PA9,PA10,PA11,PA12,PA13,PA14,PA15,PA16,PA17,PA18,PA19,PA20,PA21,PA22,PA23,PA24,PA25,PA26,PA27,PA28,PA29,PA30,PA31,PA32,PA33,PA34,PA35,PA36,PA37,PA38,PA39,PA40,PA41,PA42,PA43,PA44,PA45,PA46,PA47,PA48,PA49,PA50,PA51,PA52,PA53,PA54,PA55,PA56,PA57,PA58,PA59,PA60,PA61,PA62,PA63,PA64,PA65,PA66,PA67,PA68,PA69,PA70,PA71,PA72,PA73,PA74,PA75,PA76,PA77,PA78,PA79,PA80,PA81,PA82,PA83,PA84,PA85,PA86,PA87,PA88,PA89,PA90,PA91,PA92,PA93,PA94,PA95,PA96,PA97,PA98,PH1,PH2,PH3,PH4,PH5,PH6,PH7,PH8,PH9,PH10,PH11,PH12,PH13,PH14,PH15,PH16,PH17,PH18,PH19,PH20,PH21,PH22,PH23,PH24,PH25,PH26,PH27,PH28,PH29,PH30,PH31,PH32,PH33,PH34,PH35,PH36,PH37,PH38,PH39,PH40,PH41,PH42,PH43,PH44,PH45,PH46,PH47,PH48,PH49,PH50,TD1,TD2,TD3,TD4,TD5,TD6,TD7,TD8,TD9,TD10,TD11,TD12,TD13,TD14,TD15,ZE1,ZE2,ZE3" id="MainResidenceAddressSection-PostcodeForSearch" maxlength="4096" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.PostcodeForSearch" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-4  col-xs-3">
                    <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
                    <img alt="help" class="tooltip" id="help-MainResidenceAddressSection-PostcodeForSearch" src="/legal-services/Client/images/home/help-button.png">               </div>
            </div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MainResidenceAddressSection.PostcodeForSearch" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> 
            <div class="tooltip-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="summary-group-bottom-buttons clearfix"><a class="button-green-medium" data-address-finder-url="/legal-services/AddressLookup/FindAddress" data-postcode-search-url="/legal-services/AddressLookup/Find" id="FindHomeAddress"><span>Find Address</span></a></div>
        </div>          

        <!--Address summary-->
        <div id="MainResidenceAddressSummary" class="summary-group no-margin-top" style="display: none">
            <h3>Your main residence address</h3>
            <div class="summary-text">
                <p id="MainResidenceHousenameSummary"><strong>House name:</strong> <span></span></p>
                <p id="MainResidenceHousenumberSummary"><strong>House number:</strong> <span></span></p> 
                <p id="MainResidenceStreetSummary"><strong>Street:</strong> <span></span></p> 
                <p id="MainResidenceTownSummary"><strong>Town:</strong> <span></span></p> 
                <p id="MainResidenceCountySummary"><strong>County:</strong> <span></span></p> 
                <p id="MainResidencePostcodeSummary"><strong>Postcode:</strong> <span></span></p>  
            </div>

            <div id="MainResidenceSummaryEdit" class="summary-edit">
                <a class="blue-outline-button-small"><span>Edit</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Address list--> 
        <div id="MainResidenceAddressList" class="address-list-wrapper clearfix" style="margin-top: 20px; display: none;">
            <ul>                
            </ul>
            <p class="pull-left"><a href="#" id="EnterDifferentHomePostcode" class="">Enter a different postcode</a></p>
            <p class="pull-right"><a href="#" id="MainResidenceAddressNotListed" class="">My address is not listed</a></p>
        </div>



        <!--Address lookup-->
        <div id="MainResidenceAddessLookup" style="margin-top: 20px; display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="" for="MainResidenceAddressSection_HouseName">House name</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                    <input class="tooltip form-control" data-val="true" data-val-atleastonerequired="Please provide either your house name or house number" data-val-atleastonerequired-inputstocheck="MainResidenceAddressSection-HouseNumber,MainResidenceAddressSection-HouseName" data-val-length="Please enter a valid house name with no more than 30 characters" data-val-length-max="30" id="MainResidenceAddressSection-HouseName" maxlength="30" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.HouseName" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-4  col-xs-3">
                    <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MainResidenceAddressSection.HouseName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> 
            <div class="tooltip-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="" for="MainResidenceAddressSection_HouseNumber">House number</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                    <input class="tooltip form-control" id="MainResidenceAddressSection-HouseNumber" maxlength="4096" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.HouseNumber" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-4  col-xs-3">
                    <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MainResidenceAddressSection.HouseNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>   
            <div class="tooltip-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="" for="MainResidenceAddressSection_Street">Street</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                    <input class="tooltip form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="Please enter your valid street name with no more than 30 characters" data-val-length-max="30" data-val-required="Please enter your street name" id="MainResidenceAddressSection-Street" maxlength="30" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.Street" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-4  col-xs-3">
                    <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MainResidenceAddressSection.Street" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    
            <div class="tooltip-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="" for="MainResidenceAddressSection_Town">Town</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                    <input class="tooltip form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="Please enter a valid town name with no more than 30 characters" data-val-length-max="30" data-val-required="Please enter the town" id="MainResidenceAddressSection-Town" maxlength="30" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.Town" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-4  col-xs-3">
                    <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MainResidenceAddressSection.Town" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>  
            <div class="tooltip-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="" for="MainResidenceAddressSection_County">County</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                    <input class="tooltip form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="Please enter a valid county name with no more than 30 characters" data-val-length-max="30" id="MainResidenceAddressSection-County" maxlength="30" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.County" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-4  col-xs-3">
                    <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MainResidenceAddressSection.County" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    
            <div class="tooltip-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="" for="MainResidenceAddressSection_Postcode">Postcode</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                    <input class="tooltip form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="Please enter a valid postcode with no more than 12 characters" data-val-length-max="12" data-val-regex="Please enter a valid postcode" data-val-regex-pattern="^(([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$)" data-val-required="Please enter a postcode" data-val-restrictedpostcode="Sorry, we do not operate in the postcode provided" data-val-restrictedpostcode-postcodelist="AB1,AB2,AB3,AB4,AB5,AB6,AB7,AB8,AB9,AB10,AB11,AB12,AB13,AB14,AB15,AB16,AB17,AB18,AB19,AB20,AB21,AB22,AB23,AB24,AB25,AB26,AB27,AB28,AB29,AB30,AB31,AB32,AB33,AB34,AB35,AB36,AB37,AB38,AB39,AB40,AB41,AB42,AB43,AB44,AB45,AB46,AB47,AB48,AB49,AB50,AB51,AB52,AB53,AB54,AB55,AB56,AB57,AB58,AB59,AB60,AB61,AB62,AB63,AB64,AB65,AB66,AB67,AB68,AB69,AB70,AB71,AB72,AB73,AB74,AB75,AB76,AB77,AB78,AB79,AB80,AB81,AB82,AB83,AB84,AB85,AB86,AB87,AB88,AB89,AB90,AB91,AB92,AB93,AB94,AB95,AB96,AB97,AB98,AB99,BT1,BT2,BT3,BT4,BT5,BT6,BT7,BT8,BT9,BT10,BT11,BT12,BT13,BT14,BT15,BT16,BT17,BT18,BT19,BT20,BT21,BT22,BT23,BT24,BT25,BT26,BT27,BT28,BT29,BT30,BT31,BT32,BT33,BT34,BT35,BT36,BT37,BT38,BT39,BT40,BT41,BT42,BT43,BT44,BT45,BT46,BT47,BT48,BT49,BT50,BT51,BT52,BT53,BT54,BT55,BT56,BT57,BT58,BT59,BT60,BT61,BT62,BT63,BT64,BT65,BT66,BT67,BT68,BT69,BT70,BT71,BT72,BT73,BT74,BT75,BT76,BT77,BT78,BT79,BT80,BT81,BT82,BT83,BT84,BT85,BT86,BT87,BT88,BT89,BT90,BT91,BT92,BT93,BT94,DD1,DD2,DD3,DD4,DD5,DD6,DD7,DD8,DD9,DD10,DD11,DG1,DG2,DG3,DG4,DG5,DG6,DG7,DG8,DG9,DG10,DG11,DG12,DG13,DG14,DG15,DG16,EH1,EH2,EH3,EH4,EH5,EH6,EH7,EH8,EH9,EH10,EH11,EH12,EH13,EH14,EH15,EH16,EH17,EH18,EH19,EH20,EH21,EH22,EH23,EH24,EH25,EH26,EH27,EH28,EH29,EH30,EH31,EH32,EH33,EH34,EH35,EH36,EH37,EH38,EH39,EH40,EH41,EH42,EH43,EH44,EH45,EH46,EH47,EH48,EH49,EH50,EH51,EH52,EH53,EH54,EH55,EH56,EH57,EH58,EH59,EH60,EH61,EH62,EH63,EH64,EH65,EH66,EH67,EH68,EH69,EH70,EH71,EH72,EH73,EH74,EH75,EH76,EH77,EH78,EH79,EH80,EH81,EH82,EH83,EH84,EH85,EH86,EH87,EH88,EH89,EH90,EH91,EH92,EH93,EH94,EH95,EH96,EH97,EH98,EH99,FK1,FK2,FK3,FK4,FK5,FK6,FK7,FK8,FK9,FK10,FK11,FK12,FK13,FK14,FK15,FK16,FK17,FK18,FK19,FK20,FK21,GY1,GY2,GY3,GY4,GY5,GY6,GY7,GY8,GY9,GY10,G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,G10,G11,G12,G13,G14,G15,G16,G17,G18,G19,G20,G21,G22,G23,G24,G25,G26,G27,G28,G29,G30,G31,G32,G33,G34,G35,G36,G37,G38,G39,G40,G41,G42,G43,G44,G45,G46,G47,G48,G49,G50,G51,G52,G53,G54,G55,G56,G57,G58,G59,G60,G61,G62,G63,G64,G65,G66,G67,G68,G69,G70,G71,G72,G73,G74,G75,G76,G77,G78,G79,G80,G81,G82,G83,G84,G85,G86,G87,G88,G89,G90,HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IM1,IM2,IM3,IM4,IM5,IM6,IM7,IM8,IM9,IM86,IM87,IM99,IV1,IV2,IV3,IV4,IV5,IV6,IV7,IV8,IV9,IV10,IV11,IV12,IV13,IV14,IV15,IV16,IV17,IV18,IV19,IV20,IV21,IV22,IV23,IV24,IV25,IV26,IV27,IV28,IV29,IV30,IV31,IV32,IV33,IV34,IV35,IV36,IV37,IV38,IV39,IV40,IV41,IV42,IV43,IV44,IV45,IV46,IV47,IV48,IV49,IV50,IV51,IV52,IV53,IV54,IV55,IV56,IV57,IV58,IV59,IV60,IV61,IV62,IV63,IV64,IV65,IV66,IV67,IV68,IV69,IV70,IV71,IV72,IV73,IV74,IV75,IV76,IV77,IV78,IV79,IV80,IV81,IV82,IV83,IV84,IV85,IV86,IV87,IV88,IV89,IV90,IV91,IV92,IV93,IV94,IV95,IV96,IV97,IV98,IV99,JE1,JE2,JE3,JE4,JE5,KA1,KA2,KA3,KA4,KA5,KA6,KA7,KA8,KA9,KA10,KA11,KA12,KA13,KA14,KA15,KA16,KA17,KA18,KA19,KA20,KA21,KA22,KA23,KA24,KA25,KA26,KA27,KA28,KA29,KA30,KW1,KW2,KW3,KW4,KW5,KW6,KW7,KW8,KW9,KW10,KW11,KW12,KW13,KW14,KW15,KW16,KW17,KY1,KY2,KY3,KY4,KY5,KY6,KY7,KY8,KY9,KY10,KY11,KY12,KY13,KY14,KY15,KY16,KY99,ML1,ML2,ML3,ML4,ML5,ML6,ML7,ML8,ML9,ML10,ML11,ML12,PA1,PA2,PA3,PA4,PA5,PA6,PA7,PA8,PA9,PA10,PA11,PA12,PA13,PA14,PA15,PA16,PA17,PA18,PA19,PA20,PA21,PA22,PA23,PA24,PA25,PA26,PA27,PA28,PA29,PA30,PA31,PA32,PA33,PA34,PA35,PA36,PA37,PA38,PA39,PA40,PA41,PA42,PA43,PA44,PA45,PA46,PA47,PA48,PA49,PA50,PA51,PA52,PA53,PA54,PA55,PA56,PA57,PA58,PA59,PA60,PA61,PA62,PA63,PA64,PA65,PA66,PA67,PA68,PA69,PA70,PA71,PA72,PA73,PA74,PA75,PA76,PA77,PA78,PA79,PA80,PA81,PA82,PA83,PA84,PA85,PA86,PA87,PA88,PA89,PA90,PA91,PA92,PA93,PA94,PA95,PA96,PA97,PA98,PH1,PH2,PH3,PH4,PH5,PH6,PH7,PH8,PH9,PH10,PH11,PH12,PH13,PH14,PH15,PH16,PH17,PH18,PH19,PH20,PH21,PH22,PH23,PH24,PH25,PH26,PH27,PH28,PH29,PH30,PH31,PH32,PH33,PH34,PH35,PH36,PH37,PH38,PH39,PH40,PH41,PH42,PH43,PH44,PH45,PH46,PH47,PH48,PH49,PH50,TD1,TD2,TD3,TD4,TD5,TD6,TD7,TD8,TD9,TD10,TD11,TD12,TD13,TD14,TD15,ZE1,ZE2,ZE3" id="MainResidenceAddressSection-Postcode" maxlength="12" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.Postcode" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-4  col-xs-3">
                    <span class="valid-tick hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MainResidenceAddressSection.Postcode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>  
            <div class="tooltip-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <input id="MainResidenceAddressSection_HasMainAddress" name="MainResidenceAddressSection.HasMainAddress" type="hidden" value="False">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so `JQuery` does validation by iterating over all elements that have validation on them (no element no way to invoke validation), which means that if one wants to validate something more complex like group of elements he will have to 'fudge' it by adding validation to some parent element and start hacking from there.

Instead I introduced collection to which one can add validation function that returns `bool` if any function does not return true method is added `validationMethodErrors` if there's more than zero errors - validation fails.

so validator got `validationMethods`

```
$.validator.validationMethods = [];
```

and then got extended with

```
validationMethodErrors : [],
```

checkForm() had to become this:

```
    checkForm: function() {
        this.prepareForm();
        for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
            this.check( elements[i] );
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < $.validator.validationMethods.length; j++) {
            if (!$.validator.validationMethods[j]()) {
                this.validationMethodErrors.push($.validator.validationMethods[j]);
            }
        }

        return this.valid();
    },
```

valid() this:

```
    valid: function() {
        return this.size() == 0 && this.validationMethodErrors.length == 0;
    },
```

and then cleanup functions:

```
    reset: function() {
        this.successList = [];
        this.errorList = [];
        this.errorMap = {};
        this.toShow = $([]);
        this.toHide = $([]);
        this.currentElements = $([]);
        this.validationMethodErrors = [];
    },

    resetForm: function() {
        if ( $.fn.resetForm )
            $( this.currentForm ).resetForm();
        this.submitted = {};
        this.lastElement = null;
        this.prepareForm();
        this.hideErrors();
        this.elements().removeClass(this.settings.errorClass);
        this.validationMethodErrors = [];
    },
```

and then you just push into `validationMethods` and it works

```
    $.validator.validationMethods.push(address.onFormSubmit);
```

not to elegant but does the job.

BTW proper solution IMHO would be to switch to angular or knockout as this sort of requirement indicated that user interface is to complex.